# angular.foreach giving me duplicate data while sending get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is working but it's giving me a **duplicate data** and I can't seem find the solution.

**Here's my code.**

**vm.peoplev2 value**

```
vm.peoplev2 = [{'userId': 'admin'},{'userId':'jonas'},{'userId':'maria'},{'userId':'johncena'},{'userId':'lorenz'}];
```

**controller**

```
angular.forEach(vm.peoplev2, function (value, key) {
      console.log(value.userId);
      uploadService.getCurrentImg(value.userId).then(function (data) {
        if (value.userId === data.data.user) {
          vm.img.push(data.data);
          console.log(vm.img);
        }
   });
});
```

**uploadService**

```
function getCurrentImg(data) {
   return $http.get('/api/img/' + data );
}
```

**routes**

```
router.get('/img/:id', function (req, res) {
    Img.findOne({ user: req.params.id }, function (err, img) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send(err);;
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(img);
        }
    });
});
```

**This is the result in vm.img(object):**

[image]

It's fetching the jonas and lorenz 2x. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Async operations and loops can be unpredictable.  Try something along these lines:

(Replace the `$timeout` in the service with your `$http` calls)

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.service('service', function($timeout) {
  this.get = function(person) {
    return $timeout(() => {
      return {
        '_id': ~~Math.random(),
        'name': person.userId
      }
    }, 250)
  }
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function(service, $q) {
  this.peoplev2 = [{
    'userId': 'admin'
  }, {
    'userId': 'jonas'
  }, {
    'userId': 'maria'
  }, {
    'userId': 'johncena'
  }, {
    'userId': 'lorenz'
  }];

  $q.all(this.peoplev2.map(person => service.get(person)))
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
});
```

This creates an array of promises, and waits for all to execute before returning the final result.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DOuqAIKgwNrQNDn0BCGf?p=preview)

Comment: your plnkr is not showing anything. and ill try to test your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Open the console and run. It's a demo, not a full replication.

Comment: I think this defeat the idea of showing the already pushed data ? might as well fetch all the img data in one go ?

Comment: The point is to use `$q.all` instead of a loop. The rest moot.